# How to map Oracle NUMBER(1) to an integer instead of boolean in LinqPad 6 with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: linqpad, linqpad6

I'm using LinqPad 6 and Entity Framework Core connection. But LinqPad mapped my NUMBER(1) column from Oracle to a Boolean, how can I force it back to an Integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible right now. I'll add a checkbox to the connection dialog to accomplish this in LINQPad's next beta release.